# Store a PDF in a mySQL DB using HTML jQuery and Java

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdf

I need to store a pdf (each pdf will be < 5 pages maximum) in a mySQL database. The column is defined as mediumblob. The test pdf is 198 KB. I get the error "Errors occurred in addMedicalPlan: java.io.FileNotFoundException: " followed by a dump of the file " JVBERi0xLjcKCjQgMCBvYmoKKElkZW50aXR5KQplbmRvYmoKNS ......" and at the end "(The filename or extension is too long)".

I have managed to do this with images and have been trying to re-purpose that code to store the pdf; by researching articles and other questions on Stackoverflow. Unfortunately, for me, most of the example relate to PHP. I have been able to read the pdf and display it in the page with this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <embed width="191" height="207" id="image" src="" type="application/pdf">
    <input class="form-control-file col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 photo-input" type="file" id="photo" name="photo" placeholder="PDF">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '.photo-input', function(){
    //Check for a valid image extension
    var img1 = this.files[0].type;
    alert("img1: " + img1);
    var mySubString = img1.substring(
        img1.lastIndexOf("image") + 13
    );
    alert("mySubString: " + mySubString)
    if($.inArray(mySubString, ['pdf']) == -1) {
        alert('Add invalid extension 1!');
        $('#image').attr('src', '');
    }else{
        //Check for a valid image size
        if (this.files[0].size < 10000000){
            readURL(this, this.id);
        }else{
            alert("This image is to large (must be < 1 MB).")
            $('#image').attr('src', '');
        }
        var img1 = document.getElementById('image');
        img2 = (img1.getAttribute('src')).replace(/^data:application\/(pdf);base64,/, "");
    }
});

function readURL(input, id) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

I then pass the pdf to be stored with ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MedicalPlanAddView",
        cache: false,
        data : {
         ssAccountLevel : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevel'),
         ssAccountID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountID'),
         ssNameID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssNameID'),

         image : img2,
         mpNameAdd: $("#mpNameAdd").val(),
  }, 
})
```

And the server side java is:

```
private static byte[] getByteArrayFromFile(final String handledDocument) throws IOException {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(handledDocument);
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[500];
    int read = -1;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    in.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}

ps.setString(1, nameId);
ps.setString(2, medicalPlanName);
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new 
ByteArrayInputStream(getByteArrayFromFile(medicalPlan)); //pdf image
ps.setBlob(3, bais); 
ps.setString(4, updateDate);

ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I would not recommend storing as Blob. You could rather store the file on your hard disk, and store the path of the file as varchar (text) datatype.

Comment: your medicalPlan variable contains long string "JVBERi0xLjcKCjQgMCBvYmoKKElkZW50aXR5KQplbmRvYmoKNS ......" which you try to use as a file name. Probably the desired file has different name.

Comment: Thanks Alexei, I am passing the actual file, not the address, are you able to assist me in processing it correctly please?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <embed width="191" height="207" id="image" src="" type="application/pdf" class="img-thumbnail">
        <input class="form-control-file col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 photo-input" type="file" id="photo" name="photo" placeholder="PDF">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '.photo-input', function(){
    //Check for a valid image extension
    var img1 = this.files[0].type;
    var mySubString = img1.substring(
        img1.lastIndexOf("image") + 13
    );
        if($.inArray(mySubString, ['pdf']) == -1) {
        alert('invalid extension!');
        $('#image').attr('src', 'data:application\/(pdf);base64');
    }else{
        //Check for a valid image size
        if (this.files[0].size < 10000000){
            readURL(this, this.id);
        }else{
            alert("This image is to large (must be < 1 MB).")
            $('#image').attr('src', 'data:application\/(pdf);base64');
        }
        var img1 = document.getElementById('image');
        img2 = (img1.getAttribute('src')).replace(/^data:application\/(pdf);base64,/, "");
    }
});

function readURL(input, id) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

    submitHandler : function(showMPAddForm) {
        var img1 = document.getElementById('image');
        img2 = (img1.getAttribute('src')).replace(/^data:application\/(pdf);base64,/, "");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MedicalPlanAddView",
            cache: false,
            data : {
                ssAccountLevel : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevel'),
                ssAccountID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountID'),
                ssNameID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssNameID'),

                image : img2,
                mpNameAdd: $("#mpNameAdd").val(),
            }, 
        })
        .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse13').text('Error adding Medical Plan.');
        })
        .done(function(responseJson){
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse13').text('Medical Plan added.');
            showActionPlanDataTable();
        })
    }
```

SQL:

```
                ps = c.prepareStatement(updateWithPhoto);
                ps.setString(1, medicalPlanName);

                BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
                byte[] imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(medicalPlan);
                ps.setBlob(2, new SerialBlob(imageByte));

                ps.setString(3, updateDate);
                ps.setString(4, medicalPlanId);

                ps.executeUpdate();
```